# SSRS lookupset - row output

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am looking to use the lookupset function. I have a one to many relationship when one Risk has many Actions.

Using this function I can return it as a comma separated line, however what I really need is for each entry to display in a new row of a table, is this possible?

I have replaced the comma so instead of creating a comma separated line it does a newline, however I need it to line up with other values. This Is why I would like to to come out in rows in a table.

Answer (score 1):

Can it display on separate lines rather than separate rows? If so, then you can simply separate the fields using carriage return/line feed pairs, like so:

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!Id.Value, Fields!Id.Value, Fields!FieldToLookup.Value, "LookupDataset"), vbCrLf)
```

Otherwise you are better off defining a subreport and embedding that in your table. The subreport is simply a report that is just a table with the report taking a parameter. You add this to the table in the main report using the toolbar and then set the parameters in the subreport properties to pass in the identification field name from the table's dataset.

Comment: Hi, it needs to really be in table rows as it needs to be separated by lines like in a table and align correctly with other rows. I have tried a subreport however if I have 1000 risks then that means 1000 sub reports are being run for this one report?

Comment: Yes, it will run however many times that you have risks but it will be quick assuming everything is well indexed. Subreports are the way to do what you want.